# How to make TObjectDictionary.Values accessible as property?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009

I have an object like this:

```
  TMyObj = class
  private
    FObjList: TObjectDictionary <integer, TMyObject>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
    // How to access Values correctly? Something similar to this not working code
    property Values: TValueCollection read FObjList.Values write FObjList.Values;
  end;

  var MyObj: TMyObj;
```

To access the values of FObjList, I'd like to write:

```
  for tmpObject in MyObj.Values do
...
```

How do I need to declare the property "Values" so that MyObj.Values behaves exactly as if I would access MyObj.FObjList.Values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  /// Interface

  TMyDictionary = TObjectDictionary <integer, TMyObject>;
  TMyValueCollection = TDictionary<integer,TMyObject>.TValueCollection;

  TMyObj = class
  private
    FObjList: TMyDictionary;
    function GetValues: TMyValueCollection;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Values: TMyValueCollection read GetValues;
  end;


/// Implementation


constructor TMyObj.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FObjList := TMyDictionary.Create;
end;

destructor TMyObj.Destroy;
begin
  FObjList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TMyObj.GetValues: TMyValueCollection;
begin
  Result := FObjList.Values;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

TValueCollection is a nested class of TDictionary and has to be qualified. And you better specify a getter method for Values.

```
type   
  TMyObjectDictionary = TObjectDictionary <integer, TMyObject>;

  TMyObj = class   
  private
    FObjList: TMyObjectDictionary;
    function GetValues: TMyObjectDictionary.TValueCollection;  
  public
    property Values: TMyObjectDictionary.TValueCollection read GetValues;   
  end;

function TMyObj.GetValues: TMyObjectDictionary.TValueCollection;
begin
  Result := FObjList.Values;
end;
```

Edit: Ups! Too late...  But slightly different.